# How to filter table element based on a chosen date in calendar on angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mean-stack

Working with MEANSTACK technology, I have this situation:
One input tag with type "date" like this:

```
<input class="form-control form-control-lg" style="margin-left:5px;" type="date" ng-model="myObject.locations[0].timestamp">
```

One table containing some properties of the object myObject. it looks like this:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
                       <thead>
                         <tr>
                           <th class="col-xs-4">Date</th>
                           <th class="col-xs-4">Address </th>
                        </tr>   
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="obj in history" >
                        <td class="col-xs-4">{{obj.locations[0].timestamp | date: "dd-MM-yyyy-HH:mm:ss" }}</td>
                        <td class="col-xs-4">{{addr}}</td>
     <td class="col-xs-4">{{obj.locations[1].timestamp | date: "dd-MM-yyyy-HH:mm:ss" }}</td>
                        <td class="col-xs-4">{{addr}}</td>  
                    </tr>
              </tbody>
</table>
```

locations is a property of the object myObject that is an array containing a set of objects.It looks like this:

```
myObject:{
"p0":"value0",
"p1":"value1",
locations:[
{"long":"vlong0",
 "lat":"vlat0",
 "timestamp":"vtimestamp0"},
{"long":"vlong0",
 "lat":"vlat0",
 "timestamp":"vtimestamp0"}]
}
```

This is how I populate my table in my controller:

```
$http.get('myobject.json').success(function(response){
             $scope.history = response;
            });
```

The question is I don't find the way to filter table based on my calendar date choice and how to do it on the whole "locations" array. What should I do. Any help!

Comment: use a custom filter in ng-repeat="obj in history | <custom filter>"

Comment: The `timestamp` property in your object is just a string, not a date